# How can I get the positions data of every joint?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am doing arm trajectory planning.
Now I am using motion_planning_rviz_plugin to display the trajectory of the arm. First I wrote program reference to [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/motion_planning_rviz_plugin/Tutorials/DisplayingRobotTrajectoriesInRviz) and then RVIZ subscribe the topic "joint_path_display".
I can display the trajectory just like the picture  [image: image description]!
Now I want to get the  position data of every joints which I circled with red colour on the image.
How can I get the position information of every joint?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199543/how-can-i-get-the-positions-data-of-every-joint-?/) by [karen0603](https://answers.ros.org/users/5106/karen0603/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2014-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Set up a tf::TransformListener (http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1TransformListener.html ) from the tf package ( http://wiki.ros.org/tf ) or tf2::BufferCore ( http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf2/html/classtf2_1_1BufferCore.html ) from the tf2 package ( http://wiki.ros.org/tf2 ) --  depending on which tf version you use / your ROS distro supports and use the function lookupTransform ( http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Transformer.html#a14536fe915c0c702534409c15714aa2f  or http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf2/html/classtf2_1_1BufferCore.html#a362de8ea45b99efde65bcc602053ad38 ) .................

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karen0603](https://answers.ros.org/users/5106/karen0603/) on 2014-12-16**:
Thank you, I will try to do what you have suggested. I am using Fuerte.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-12-16**:
then it'd be tf not tf2

**Comment by [karen0603](https://answers.ros.org/users/5106/karen0603/) on 2014-12-16**:
Thank you very much, I am using  planning of motion_planning_rviz_plugin to display the pose of every joint, I am wondering if I can get pose information directly from motion_planning_rviz_plugin::planning?
Thank you